# How can I make all the object particles point upward in a cone fashion?

Tags: modeling, particles, weight-painting, hair

I'm making another branch for my tree model this time I want it to look like a white pine that I modeled it off of google images. The leaves should be moving more upward in a V shape/ cone shape while maintaining a puff ball design. However, there still pointed outward from the face of the mesh I tried playing around with the ParticleSystem property tab's menu such as using "object" in "render as" then selecting the leaf model in "instance object" and for the vertex groups I chose "density" by marking the areas in wightpaint mode so the leaves will only target the end tips of the branch, but this was the best I could do. Is there any other way I can reshape it?[image]

[image]

Comment: i am not sure whether this is possible at all with particles...but for sure it would be possible with geometry nodes.

Comment: @Chris It is possible with _Hair_ particles, but I guess _Geometry Nodes_ would be better for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled *Advanced* on the *Hair* settings. You can make them all point upwards (or downwards) by changing the settings for *Tangent* and *Tangent Phase* under *Velocity*. You can also add a small amount of randomness with *Randomize* so that they are not so uniformly oriented.

[image: hair tangent velocity]

**//EDIT:** As discussed in the comments, there are problems with the orientation of the leaves if you are changing the velocities for *Tangent* and *Tangent Phase*. It turns out that of course the face normals are always pointing outside perpendicular to the face, but (I did not know it before) the orientation of the UVs has an influence on the tangent.

So as a starting point let's have a closer look at one of the branches from your model (I have disabled the leaves and made the paths shorter for a better overview, also I show *Edit Mode* and *Object Mode* in comparison). This is how the UVs of the branch look and how the paths are oriented without any velocity for the tangents:

[image: initial state]

First of all you can see that the UVs are quite messed up in comparison to the actual mesh. I will talk about the UVs later.

Then you can see how the orientation towards the tip is changing from sideways to forward, simply speaking. Imagine that when you now rotate all 45° away in some direction from their upright position according to the normal, the ones already pointing in the desired direction will stray away from it.

What I recommend is deleting the very last face on the top closing the branch. The leaves should cover up the hole if you do not look too close and you can also scale it smaller maybe. Now you can see, all hair paths are pointing sideways from the branch, none are pointing forward.

[image: deleting the top face]

Notice that the only real UV face is now gone, meaning the other branch UVs are just edges in the UV map. And if you now give a bit of velocity on the *Tangent* and *Tangent Phase*, the result looks terrible and they are all oriented differently:

[image: different orientations]

Then I realized that the different orientation of the UVs could be a reason for the paths changing directions. Taking the individual edges in the UV map, leaving one as it is, rotating one by 90°, the other by -90° and the last by 180°, the paths looked a lot better:

[image: new orientation of UVs]

However, it was just a guess as how to rotate the edges. And maybe not all UVs are oriented in a way that makes guessing easy. So I thought giving the mesh a new UV unwrap would be better, and I used U > *Smart UV Project*, which is always good for a quick automatic unwrap. The result is better than the initial mess, but not as good as the manual rotation before:

[image: smart uv project]

They are also (for the most part) pointed in the opposite direction of what is desired. This could of course be changed with the velocity for *Tangent* and *Tangent Phase* or by just rotating the UVs by 180° in the UV Map:

[image: rotating the UVs]

Still not perfect. So I thought I should make all UVs basically the same. Therefore you can choose U > *Reset* as unwrapping method. This simply places each face individually onto the UV map so that it fits the area, in the case of quads they just become squares filling the complete UV map:

[image: reset uv faces]

This gives a quite good result, and if you could spot a face where the paths are oriented differently than all the others, just select this one and rotate it 90°, 180° or 270° until it is correct. If you now add a little *Randomize* velocity to make it appear a little more natural it should be okay:

[image: randomize velocity]

Here is the final result (your file did not contain the wood textures, so I just gave a color to the branch):

[image: final branch]

By the way, I have disabled *Rotation* in the particle settings - but the values for *Phase* and *Randomize Phase* still have an influence on how the leaves look, enabling *Rotation* just lets you edit those values:

[image: changing rotation phase]

Comment: I copied what you wrote in the image but after tweaking with tangent, tangent phase, randomize I still wasn't able to get the leaves to point up they just look like puff balls.

Comment: @Stephen I imported your mesh into my file and put my hair system onto your mesh and it did not work either. I even applied the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier which did not help, took just a ring of the subdivided mesh and extruded it to get new faces. Did not work. But eventually I found the reason: it's the UVs. So I went into _Edit Mode_, selected all and hit `U` > _Smart UV Project_, and now it worked. You could also just choose _Reset_, the values for _Tangent_ and _Tangent Phase_ will be different, but both will make it work.

Comment: It seems to be working but how do you reset?

Comment: Also, I notice that any branch above the horizontal 90-degree mark have their leaves pointed upward but any branch pointed below the horizontal mark have their leaves facing downward, why does it do that, and can it be fixed so they can all be pointed upwards?

Comment: @Stephen _Reset_ is one of the unwrapping options, press `U` > _Reset_. After testing I think it is the better option to make the leaves point more in the same direction, because the orientation of the UV faces makes a difference for the _Tangent_. But since they are oriented along their normals, the ones on the closing faces of each tip will always be pointing in different directions than the ones on the side, so I would rather leave the tip open to have only leaves pointing outwards the side of the branches and not "forward" from the tip. I'll edit in examples in my answer later.

Comment: @Stephen I've edited my answer to make the method work with your branch mesh and well, maybe it is a bit too detailed but I wanted to show the process of how I found the way to the end result.

Answer (score 2):

You could make the pines go one direction this way, enable the *Advanced* option, disable *Hair Dynamics*, enable *Rotation*, and select *Orientation Axis > Velocity/Hair*:

[image]

Then create a *Force Field* like for example a *Force* and give it a negative *Strength*, the pines will be attracted towards the force field:

[image]

Comment: Using a force field seems a bit elaborate and complicated to me...  will the pines keep the orientation when instanced on a tree or do you have to instance force fields with them? Have no object to test it atm.

Comment: You can duplicate your branch and rotate a bit, they will roughly keep the same orientation, then convert the particles to mesh and use the branches as particles themselves, or Alt D?

Comment: It does seem to work but the leaves all follow the same force when I want them to point out in different directions based on the branches.  This is especially noticeable when I crank up the strength.